# TypeError - descriptor read for _io.BytesIO objects doesn't apply to list object when reading data from list into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In the following lines of code I'm trying to get data into Pandas Dataframe from list using Python37-32,

```
rows_list = []

raw_data = io.BytesIO((zfile2.read(name=data_file_name)))

with  raw_data as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        cleaned_line = cleanup(line)
        rows_list.append(cleaned_line)

df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO.read(rows_list), sep='|',  escapechar='\\')
```

I'm getting this error - `TypeError("descriptor 'read' for '_io.BytesIO' objects doesn't apply to 'list' object"`

Can somebody please point me to right direction for solving this.
Really appreciate your time and advice.
Thanks!

Comment: BytesIO.read needs just  bytes, not a list of bytes, so it woud be `BytesIO.read(b'\n'.join(rows_list))`

Comment: @Stef - made changes as you suggested, same error but for bytes-  read doesn't apply to 'bytes' object

Comment: sorry, it must be `BytesIO(b'\n'.join(rows_list))` without the read.

Comment: @Stef - thanks for reply. I'm able to get the list data into dataframe now, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the changes as suggested by Stef (refer comment section), and I'm able to get the list data into dataframe.

```
rows_list = []

raw_data = io.BytesIO((zfile2.read(name=data_file_name)))

with  raw_data as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        cleaned_line = cleanup(line)
        rows_list.append(cleaned_line.encode())

df = pd.read_csv((BytesIO(b'\n'.join(rows_list))), sep='|',  escapechar='\\')
```